# How to get dynamically a version folder name, on a cronjob?

Tags: linux, bash, cron

I have a cronjob very simple:

```sh
#! /bin/bash -l

ps cax | grep PM2
if [ $? -eq 0 ]; then
  echo $(date -u) - "PM2 is running."
else
  echo $(date -u) - "Restarting PM2."
  cd ~/public_html/
  /home/test/.nvm/versions/node/v10.21.0/bin/pm2 start index.js
fi
```

The problem appears when my hosting updates the node, and path has change in:

```
/home/test/.nvm/versions/node/v10.22.0/bin/pm2
```

and of course the cron fails to run the command. It's there a way to dynamically get that new version folder name?

Comment: Tangentially, [Why is testing ”$?” to see if a command succeeded or not, an anti-pattern?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36313216/why-is-testing-to-see-if-a-command-succeeded-or-not-an-anti-pattern)

Answer (score 0):

If you always have only one changing version, you could use find:

```
pm2=$(find /home/test/.nvm/versions/node -name pm2)
$pm2 start index.js
```

If `node` might contain other files named `pm2`, you could make sure it's in a `bin` directory:

```
pm2=$(find /home/test/.nvm/versions/node/*/bin -name pm2)
#or
pm2=$(find /home/test/.nvm/versions/node/ -name pm2 -wholename '*/bin/*')
```

And you could also execute it directly:

```
find /home/test/.nvm/versions/node/*/bin -name pm2 -exec "{}" start index.js \;
```

Look at `man find` for it's many options.

But you could also simply call it like

```
/home/test/.nvm/versions/node/*/bin/pm2 start index.js
```